# Wordpress Add Pagination to SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, pagination

i have used custom SQL query fetch the posts and set the order of the posts by custom field  date values in ASC order.

for that i have used custom SQL Query

```
        if($_GET['sort'] == 'date'){
            $posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM delitti100174_postmeta Where meta_key='data_della_scomparsa' Order By STR_TO_DATE(meta_value,'%d/%m/%Y') DESC"); 
        }else{
            $posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM delitti100174_postmeta Where meta_key='data_della_scomparsa' Order By STR_TO_DATE(meta_value,'%d/%m/%Y') ASC"); 

        }


    foreach($posts as $post){
                $po = get_post($post->post_id, ARRAY_A);
                if($po['post_status']=='publish'){
  echo get_the_title($po['ID']); 
}}
```

Which Returns 15 Records. while i want to set the pagination to display only 12 posts per page.

as i have used custom Sql Query that's why i can not use the Wp-Pagenvi Wordpress Pagination Plugin..

How can i add Pagination here. need help to integrate the Pagination.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you gone [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399892/pagination-not-showing-on-custom-query-get-results) or [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21626/pagination-with-custom-sql-query) ?

Comment: You should be able to do that with MySQL's `limit` clause (eg `SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;` retrieves rows 6-15)

Comment: but how can i get pagination there?

Comment: If memory serves, the first number would be `(current page - 1) * page size`; the second number would be `page size`.  I'm assuming you know both of those?